# É possível usar diferentes versões do PHP no lampp

Tags: php, linux, lamp

Estou usando linux Manjaro com o servidor local lampp, porém a versão do meu php é 7.2 mas quero usar a 5.6 para fazer alguns testes, minha pergunta é se é possível eu fazer esse procedimento usando o lampp ?

Comment: Olá, amigo para isso você tem que desinstalar a versão que você tem, se não vai dar conflito e o sistema não vai aceitar por que você tem uma versão mais recente instalada. ou seja, ou uma ou outra, o que eu indicaria é criar uma vm e instalar o lamp com a versão do php que você deseja, dai poderá ligar e desligar a hora que que quiser.

Comment: Você tentou instalar em outra pasta ? Exemplo: o padrão é `/opt/lampp`, coloque `/opt/lampp2`, assim cada pasta tem seus arquivos, e você sobe os serviços do qual quiser (claro que se for usar os 2, terá que usar portas diferentes).

Comment: Ou, outra forma: [Como instalar versões diferentes do PHP (5.6, 7.0 e 7.1) no Ubuntu](https://sempreupdate.com.br/como-instalar-versoes-diferentes-do-php-5-6-7-0-e-7-1-no-ubuntu/)